# Python Turtle Colour Flashing Challenge

Tags: python, colors, python-turtle

Is there a way in python turtle I can make draw a colored dot in which the color flashes or blinks? I want to highlight the largest dot drawn from a for loop loop with dots of random sizes and random colors and I want to be able to make the largest one keep changing color.

Comment: You will probably need to keep redrawing the dot the make it 'flash'

Comment: @Mike67, not necessary.  Just make the dots themselves turtles and change the turtle color on a timed event.  No (re)drawing necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I wrote for you...

```
from turtle import *

pen = Turtle()

colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]

while 1:
    i = 0
    for x in range(len(colors)):
        pen.dot(100, colors[i])
        i += 1
```